# Warning: file_exists(): ERROR

Tags: php, wordpress

In full:

> Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect.
>   File(/web/conf/gd-wordpress.conf) is not within the allowed path(s):
>   (E:/Data//bang-olufsen-repair.com\;C:\Windows\Temp) in
>   E:\Data\bang-olufsen-repair.com\testsitetestground.com\wp-content\mu-plugins\gd-system-plugin\class-gd-system-plugin-config.php on line 78

Website runs on a shared server as you'll no doubt notice, was updating plugin when it seemed to just time out then everything has been out of action since then on the testsitetestground domain.

Server guys don't know what the problem is as their backups aren't fixing it and site now displays "Error establishing a database connection"  First time I've encountered a problem such as this so any help is appreciated.

N

Comment: You need new server guys.

Comment: @rjdown I've not wanted to point any fingers or make a fuss thus far as I'm not clued up on this area but something tells me they should know more on this and that restoring a backup should surely overwrite whatever the problem is?

Comment: That really depends on what they are restoring, and what was changed in the first place. It's impossible to tell from the information you are able to provide. If restoring backups is the limit of their help, I really do strongly suggest looking for another host.

Comment: Regarding the `Error establishing a database connection`, can you confirm that your database access configuration files were correctly restored from that backup and if the contents of such [credentials] files are correct?

Answer (score 0):

> Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect.
>   File(/web/conf/gd-wordpress.conf)

This error is showing because the server is restricting your access to the /web/conf directory.  I'm assuming you are seeing this error as a surprise because you are supposed to be accessing a relative path (`web/conf`) instead of an absolute path (`/web/conf`).  A prefix of `/` makes a very big difference.

If your site was running from `/var/www/html`, a path of `web` would be at `/var/www/html/web`, while `/web` would try to access the web folder in the root directory of the server.